# Does firebase-admin override firestore security rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

If the security rule for read/write access is set to require auth will firebase-admin be able to read/write without authentication?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Firebase Admin SDKs access your database using a service account. Service accounts ignore the Cloud Firestore Security Rules, similar to how you can edit documents in the Firebase Console directly yourself.

Taken from the [Cloud Firestore Security Rules: Getting Started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) documentation:

> Note: The server client libraries bypass all Cloud Firestore Security Rules and instead authenticate through Google Application Default Credentials.